# Find iTunes songs with specific format (MPEG 1, Layer 2)

Tags: itunes

Recently I discovered that my iTunes Library contains songs with the MPEG-1, Layer 2 format.
It's impossible to sync them to my iPod. So I want to convert them to AAC or MP3.
But therefor I need a list of all songs that have that format.

Is there any way to get a list of all MPEG-1 Layer 2 formatted tracks in my iTunes library? To make things a little bit harder, they all have mp3 as extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files have mp3 as the extension, `mdfind kMDItemContentType==public.mp2` or searching for `kind:mp2` in Finder won't work either.

You could try using mplayer's command line utility. It can be installed with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) or other package managers.

`IFS=$'\n'; for f in $(find ~/Music -name *.mp3); do mplayer -identify -frames 0 "$f" 2> /dev/null | grep -q 'layer-2 audio' && echo mv "$f" ~/Desktop/; done`

Answer (score 0):

You can make a smart playlist with;

Media Kind : is : Music

Kind : contains : MPEG[image]

I do not know if you can specify "MPEG-1 Layer 2", but it couldn't hurt to try.

Comment: unfortunately `MPEG` matches mp3 too. And anything else (e.g. "Layer 2", "Layer" or just "2") does yield no results at all.